# Remove files if command not sucessful

Tags: windows, command-line, video, batch

I mux mp4 videos and webm videos with srt (subtitles) files. All the files have the same filenames but different extensions. Like this:

```
Video1.mp4
Video1.srt
```

or

```
Video2.webm
Video2.srt
```

Sometimes the muxing (merge video with subtitles) is not successful because the srt file is empty. The command line tool I use to merge video with subtitles is called MKVMerge and has 3 exit codes:

0 -- This exit codes means that muxing has completed successfully.

1 -- In this case mkvmerge(1) has output at least one warning, but muxing did continue. A warning is prefixed with the text 'Warning:'. Depending on the issues involved the resulting file might be ok or not. The user is urged to check both the warning and the resulting file.

2 -- This exit code is used after an error occurred. mkvmerge(1) aborts right after outputting the error message. Error messages range from wrong command line arguments over read/write errors to broken files.

I want a command to remove the SRT file if the error code is 1.

Here's what I'm using:

```
FOR /R "D:\Folder" %%A IN (*.mp4 *.webm) do (
"D:\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nxA" "%%~A" --language 0:eng "%%~nA.srt"
)
```

I want that command line to remove the .srt file (which uses the same filename as mp4 or webm) if the error code is 1 (one).

Comment: [Errorlevel - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

Comment: I know about ERRORLEVEL, but I can only perform simple tasks. I don't know how to append when there's a lot of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want that command line to remove the .srt file if the error code is 1.

Look at the error level set by `mkvmerge`.

Try the following batch file:

```
FOR /R "D:\Folder" %%A IN (*.mp4 *.webm) do (
  "D:\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nxA" "%%~A" --language 0:eng "%%~nA.srt"
  if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    del /q "%%~nA.srt"
  )
)
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Del - Delete Files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [Errorlevel - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)